# Pass compile options to rbenv::gem

Tags: puppet

I am using alup/puppet-rbenv and I am installing Passenger with nginx with this statement:

```
  rbenv::gem { "passenger":
    user   => "vagrant",
    ruby   => "1.9.3-p327",
    ensure => "4.0.8",
  }
```

However I need to add the following options to compile nginx:

```
--with-http_ssl_module --with-cc-opt=-Wno-error --with-http_realip_module
```

I do not know how to do it

Answer (score 0):

You will likely need to use an exec statement

```
  exec {'foo':
   command => "gem install passenger --with-http_ssl_module --with-cc-opt=-Wno-error --with-http_realip_module",
  }
```

Unfortunately you loose your [idempotence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence) by using exec.